# Disable 'outside click' on 'FAB Speed Dialog' from Angular Material

Tags: javascript, angular-material

According this pen: http://codepen.io/kuhnroyal/pen/zrEpXK when you click outside the element (outside click) it closes the FAB Dial.

```
  <md-fab-speed-dial md-trigger="click" md-direction="down" class="md-scale md-fab-top-right">
    <md-fab-trigger>
      <md-button aria-label="menu" class="md-fab md-warn">
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
      </md-button>
    </md-fab-trigger>
    <md-fab-actions>
      <md-button aria-label="Create Data App" class="md-fab md-raised md-mini" ng-click="action($event)">
        <md-tooltip>Create Data App</md-tooltip>
      </md-button>
    </md-fab-actions>
  </md-fab-speed-dial>
```

This pen is developed to still showing up when you click on its children, I wanna the same behavior but when you click outside.

PS: The only workaround that I've got is to comment the line: `10072` in `angular-material.js` which consist in close the FAB when you click outside:

```
function checkForOutsideClick(event) {
  if (event.target) {
    var closestTrigger = $mdUtil.getClosest(event.target, 'md-fab-trigger');
    var closestActions = $mdUtil.getClosest(event.target, 'md-fab-actions');

    if (!closestTrigger && !closestActions) {
      // vm.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FAB Speed Dial does not currently offer a way to customize this interaction, so you'll definitely need to modify the code a bit to make it work like you want. Your solution seems valid.

The team has discussed adding a `md-is-locked-open` attribute (https://github.com/angular/material/issues/4973) so that users can better control this behavior, but it has not been implemented yet and is not currently a priority.

Answer (score 1):

I had a use case where I wanted the same behavior. However, I like to avoid modifying 3rd party source code whenever possible.

The best way to override the default behavior of an angular directive is to use a decorator.

This article was helpful - http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/09/experiment-decorating-directives/

This snippet below works for me with angular-material 0.11.0

```
angular
.module('app')
.config( $provide => { 
     $provide.decorator('mdFabSpeedDialDirective', ($delegate, $controller) => {
          let directive = $delegate[0];

          let controllerName = directive.controller;

          directive.controller = (['$scope', '$element', '$animate', '$mdUtil', '$mdConstant', ($scope, $element, $animate, $mdUtil, $mdConstant) => {
              let controller = $controller(controllerName, {$scope : $scope, $element : $element, $animate : $animate, $mdUtil : $mdUtil, $mdConstant : $mdConstant});
               controller.close = () => {return};
               return controller;
          }]);

          return $delegate;
     });
});
```

Comment: Some changes were made here to accommodate for minification. Also beware of the 'vm.isOpen' watcher. I found that it was preventing default actions on critical keystrokes (spacebar for example) when the fab was open